# Как запретить просмотр серверных файлов?

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, nginx, vds

У меня есть сайт/веб-приложение (node.js) на VDS. Как мне запретить просмотр серверных файлов из браузерной строки?
К примеру, example.com/app/main.js

Comment: Не класть их в папку доступную для скачивания файлов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Теоретически, можно блокировать запросы без заголовка referer (в nginx).

```
if ($http_referer = "") {  return 403; }
```

На практике, некоторые клиенты могут его и так не отправлять.

Поэтому, если эти "серверные файлы" на деле должны загружаться в браузере при загрузке страницы, не надо их блокировать вообще. Иначе ни к чему хорошему в итоге это не приведёт, а пользы будет мало.